# Representing antisymmetric matrix in block diagonal form?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

I am tasked to show that an antisymmetric matrix $A$ can be expressed in block diagonal form with each block being a 2x2 antisymmetric matrix or a zero submatrix. (I get that odd-dimensions can’t be expressed this way.)

The hints given in the problem were as such:
1) to consider the eigenvectors of $A^2$ (which I know is symmetric), and 2) to notice that the non-vanishing eigenvalues of $A^2$ come in pairs.

I am able to prove, via the scalar product, that two eigenvectors of $A^2$ with the same (non-zero) eigenvalues are orthogonal. However, beyond this, I am unable to move beyond this. I am unsure of how to prove hint 2), and hint 1) leads me nowhere. Could someone guide me along the right direction? Cheers!

Comment: Sorry, I don’t understand – why can’t even matrices fulfil this? I get that odd dimension matrices have vanishing eigenvalues.

Comment: Yes, so shouldn’t this statement apply to even dimensional antisymmetric matrices?

Comment: It does, but the statement would be cleaner if you remove the condition on the size of the zero sub-block. That is, any antisymmetric matrix (of any dimension) can be expressed (via orthogonal equivalence) in a block-diagonal form, each of whose diagonal sub-blocks is either a 2x2 nonzero antisymmetric matrices or a zero sub-block.

Comment: Ah I may have misread my task. What is orthogonal equivalence?

Comment: Same as orthogonal similarity. That is, there exists an orthogonal matrix $Q$ such that $Q^TAQ$ is of the said block-diagonal form.